# Pipe network analysis: static pressure of a closed-loop pipe

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, pipelines

I've learned fluid dynamics but does not have much knowledge about its real-world applications.
My question is about the static pressure of a closed-loop pipe.

[image: Pipe network. source: Wikipedia]
[Fig. 1. Pipe network. Source: Wikipedia [Pipe_network_analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipe_network_analysis)]

According to the [pipe network analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipe_network_analysis), two conditions are satisfied for a steady-state closed-loop pipe flow.

1. At any junction, the total flow into a junction equals the total flow out of that junction.
2. Between any two junctions, the head loss is independent of the path taken. This is equivalent mathematically to the statement that on any closed loop in the network, the head loss around the loop must vanish.

I can understand above fundamental laws for the pipe network analysis.
However, I have difficulty analyzing the static pressure of each junction (not the head loss between two junctions).

Let a pump is located between J3 and J6 of Fig. 1.
Then following conditions will be hold:

1. $Q_{in}=Q_{out}$
2. $P_{6} - P_{3} =$ (actual head loss of the pump)
3. $(P_{6} - P_{3})$ and $Q_{in}=Q_{out}$ are related by the pump characteristic curve.

Above five (2+3) conditions just tell about the pressure difference, not the absolute pressure value itself.
If the pump is turned off (i.e. no flow and no head loss) and there is no valve, each joint would have a same absolute pressure value which is determined by the total volume and mass of the fluid filled within the pipe network.

However, what will be the absolute value of $P_{3}$ and $P_{6}$ when the pump is operated?
Does the absolute pressure of each joint maitain a steady value for a steady pipe network?
If so, which factor determines the steady-absolute pressure value of each joint?
Or, can the steady-absolute pressure value vary depending on transient fluctuations during the pump turn-on period?
Or, can the absolute pressure value vary even for a steady pip network?

Comment: The analysis is analogous to an electrical network -- network theorems like Norton or Thevenin (and other more modern ones) can be applied - writing out system of equations. Sometimes it can be made easier by transforming the network into a series of "voltage dividers", sometimes some algebraic manipulation is unavoidable. If flow is laminar, the analogy to impedance is just like a resistor. Otherwise the impedances are also nonlinear, but that is completely separate from the network analysis, which is done in terms of a-priori-unknown "impedance" of segments: Z_1,2 = (P_2 - P_1) / Q_1,2 etc

Comment: There is nothing in your math model to determine the absolute pressure, and (within practical limits) the absolute pressure makes no difference to the flow. A real world closed-loop system (e.g. a domestic heating system with a pump, boiler, and radiators) has an *external* connection that is opened to set the absolute pressure and closed when the system is running - and also a device to *monitor* the absolute pressure and shut the system down if it goes outside its safe operating limits.

Comment: @PeteW Thank you for your comment. Yes, this question is somewhat related to an electrical network. In case of a closed-loop electrical circuit without a ground, it is possible to calculate the voltage difference between two junctions. The term 'absolute voltage' is uncertain because the voltage meter requires two measuring point.

Comment: Then, what if we measure the voltage difference between a junction and ground (like a gauge pressure meter with one-measuring point)? There is no constraint to determine this voltage difference. If so, will this value be continuosly changed? Or will it maintain a fixed value? My question is a fluid-dynamics version of this question.

Comment: @alephzero Thank you for your comment. I agree that the absolute pressure does not affect the fluid dynamics and only related to the safety problem. This question is originated from this safety problem. In my system, the absolute pressure value fluctuates during the pump operation. I want to identify this is a common operation or a failure that can cause an extreme high pressure situation.

Comment: @J. Choi -- Yes, I think "voltage" is analogous to "gauge pressure". In principle, the entire network between J3 and J6 can be reduced to an "equivalent impedance" -- call it Z_3,6. Whether or not this impedance is linear (i.e. independent of flow), or "resistive" (i.e. no reactive component analogous to "capacitance" or "inductance" in the electrical world), Z_3,6 can still be expressed the same way in terms of all the individual Z_x,y expressions, for each of the lines in the graph. So the network analysis is just to figure out that Z_3,6 expression.

Comment: What's downstream of $\mathsf{J3}$, i.e. where does that flow $Q_{\textrm{out}}$ go?  If it eventually gets to somewhere that's open to the atmosphere, and therefore at atmospheric pressure, then you have a reference absolute pressure at that point, and can add on the pressure differences to find.  However, watch out: if the flow is turbulent, the Darcy-Weisbach equation only relates the Reynolds averages of flow rate and pressure difference, it doesn't guarantee that there will be no fluctuations about those values.

Comment: @Daniel Hatton In case of J3, it is assumed in the problem that it is connected to  J6; I've assumed a closed condition, not a open one. The second opinion, Darcy-Weisbach does not say anything about the fluctuation, is the key question of this problem. There would (may) be some fluctuations but I could not find any analysis related to it.

Comment: @J.Choi Ouch.  If you want absolute pressures in such a completely closed system, you're going to have a much harder job.  You'll at least need to know the total mass of fluid in the system, and use an integral constraint along the lines of equation 3 of your self-answer (but complicated by the existence of internal spaces in the pump); and you might also have to model the elastic deformation of the pipe walls.  What's the application?

Comment: @Daniel Hatton Thank you for your idea about the elastic deformation of a pipe wall. I agree that if I assume such a small compression of the fluid, I should also consider the pipe wall deformation. Two-phase flow assumption also seems to be valid. My application is just a closed-loop hot water circulation pipe for a building. Its real-world pressure (w.r.t. free air) data show heavy fluctuation: 250 kPa +- 25% during the pump operation. I've tried to identify the reason of this fluctuation and found that there seems to be no method to identify the absolute pressure within a pipe flow.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my question. Any feedback would be helpful.

Suppose a simple pipe loop with only one path from the pump outlet to the pump inlet.
i.e. [Pump]-[Pipe]-(any)[Load]-[Pipe]-(again)[Pump]

[Assumption] Neglect effects of other system components and pipe bending.
[Def.] Let the stream direction as $s$.
[Def.] Let the total pipe path length as $L$.
[Def.] Let the total mass of the fluid filled within the pipe as $m$.

There are three variables to be determined: $P_{in}$, $P_{out}$, and $Q$.
($P_{out}$ and $P_{in}$ are the pressure values of pump outlet and inlet flow, respectively.)
Three equations are needed to solve this problem.

1. [Pump characteristic] $P_{out} - P_{in} = f_{pump} ( Q )$.
2. [System curve] $P_{out} - P_{in} = f_{pump} ( Q ) = k L Q^{n}$ where $k$ is the friction factor.
3. [Mass conservation] $m = \int_{0}^{L} \rho(P,T)Ads = \int_{0}^{L} \rho(P_{in} + k s Q^{n},T)Ads$

There are two issues related to the Equation 3.

1. Equation 3 assumes a compressible flow (otherwise, it is meaningless). The compressible effect also has to be applied to other two equations.
2. Bulk modulus of water is quite high. The compressible flow assumption does not make much sense for water.

Comment: (2) is wrong, P_out = P_in *-* kLQ^n put another way flow is alsways high pressure to low & flow causes pressure loss, not gain. (1) looks ok, (3) I didn't check en detail, water is incompressible for our purposes (even gases can be treated as incompressible when the pressure loss is low) so it should be far simpler.

Comment: @mart Thanks, I missed the sign. In case of the compressible flow assumption, I agree that it does not make much sense but there is no other equation I can think.

Comment: mass conversation is accounted for for all nodes with Q_in = Q_3 + Q_9 (one equation for each node plus one for the network)

Comment: @mart I agree that the name 'mass conservation' in this answer caused some misunderstanding. Q_in=Q_3+Q_9 stands for the mass conservation for each node; while (3) stands for the mass conservation for the total fluid within the closed-loop pipe.

Comment: Mass conversation of the whole network is counted for by Q:in = Q_out. What's the use of the very complicated integration at [3]?

Comment: @mart Suppose a simple closed-loop pipe (without the complicated network). The diagram becomes [pump]-[pipe]-[any load]-[pipe]-(again)[pump]. Equation (1) and (2) can help to identify P_out-P_in and Q=Q_in=Q_out. However, if you want to identify P_out and P_in, additional relationship between P and Q has to be known (because there are three unknowns P_in, P_out, and Q, three equations are required.) You can apply (3) as this relationship. However, Q_in=Q_out does not say anything.

Comment: @mart Equation 3 has the total mass of water inside the network (including the direct, pumped connection between 3 and 6) before the pump is energised on the left-hand side, and the total mass of water inside the network (including the direct, pumped connection between 3 and 6) after the pump is energised on the right-hand side: since the network is completely sealed, they must be equal.

Comment: @J.Choi even if the fluid is perfectly incompressible, equation 3 still has a pressure-dependence that can be used to find the absolute pressure (or strictly speaking, the pressure relative to the outside atmospheric pressure), because $A$ and $\mathsf{d}\,s$ (and $L$) depend on pressure through the hoop strain and axial strain that the pressure induces in the pipe walls.